# Laravel. Button in FORM tag doesn't work like the others

Tags: forms, laravel, button

The buttons inside my panel-body doesn't work. This is the code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <table border="3">
                    <!-- <div id="tray"></div> -->
                    @forelse($carts as $cart)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1">{{$cart->id}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">{{$cart->name}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="row clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <form action="/restaurant/minus" method="POST">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="trayid" id="trayid" value="{{$cart->id}}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="trayprice" id="trayprice" value="{{$cart->price}}">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" style="border-radius: 50%;" id="{{$menu->id}}"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input type="number" min="1" value="{{$cart->quantity}}" style="width:40px;">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <form  action="/restaurant/plus" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="trayid" id="trayid" value="{{$cart->id}}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="trayprice" id="trayprice" value="{{$cart->price}}">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" style="border-radius: 50%"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="trayprice" value="{{$cart->price}}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <form action="/restaurant/delete" method="post">
                                    <input type="text" name="deleteid" id="deleteid" value="{{$cart->id}}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="border-radius: 50%;"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                    @empty
                    @endforelse
                </table>
            </div>
```

Meanwhile, the button in my panel-header works, and it just clears the body.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row clearix">
                    <form class="col-md-12" method="POST" action="/restaurant/cleartray">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <p class="pull-left">Tray</p>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-eraser" aria-hidden="true"></i> Clear</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is there anything wrong with the structure that made it impossible for the button to work?

P.S: It doesn't even gets to the route target. It doesn't refresh or something like that. It's like the button itself is unresponsive.

EDIT: I found out that the buttons in the form doesn't work once it's inside the forelse loop.

Comment: You seem to forget `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your `form` in the `forelse` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda got the answer by literally debugging it, haha.

It turns out that having a form tag inside the table tag isn't going to go well. So I took out the table tag. (Didn't remember why I had it in the first place)

Aaaaand voila! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your route action like:

```
<form  action="/restaurant/plus" method="post">
```

**TO**

```
<form  action="{{ url('restaurant/plus') }}" method="post">
```

Hope this work for you!